# Including Gloobal variable inside function php

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I'm trying to include globals variable inside function in php but something doesn't work.

Tried but don't work:

```
$row = fetch_row("SELECT id,name FROM $GLOBALS['var'] where id = $id");
or
$row = fetch_row("SELECT id,name FROM `$GLOBALS['var']` where id = $id");
or
$row = fetch_row("SELECT id,name FROM '$GLOBALS['var']' where id = $id");
or
$row = fetch_row("SELECT id,name FROM $GLOBALS[\"var\"] where id = $id");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using `" "` you can include variables inside a string, however, because you're trying to access an array value this will throw an error.

What you can do in this situation is either concatenate the string or wrap the variable in `{ }`.

So this:

```
"SELECT id,name FROM " . $GLOBALS['var']. " where id = $id"
```

or

```
"SELECT id,name FROM {$GLOBALS['var']} where id = $id"
```

Furthermore, you're not actually inside the function at this point, you're just passing that string to it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As it is stated on the [`variable scope in PhP`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) documentation, variables inside a script are not shared with their functions.

You will need to include them manually using `global` keyword, followed by the variables you need to process inside the function. I will copy/paste the example of the same page of documentation because it is perfectly clear what it happens :

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    function Sum()
    {
        global $a, $b;

        $b = $a + $b;
    } 

    Sum();
    echo $b;
?>
```

Which will echo :

```
3
```

The function used the value of `$a` and `$b`, which have been set outside the function. If you had not use the line `global $a, $b;`, it would throw an error saying these variables cannot be found.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['var']` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work , you have to declare which global variable you wants to access
with `global` keyword. and string format of variable written.

```
global $var;
```

after declare you can use the following query:

```
fetch_row("SELECT id,name FROM  {$GLOBALS['var']} where id = $id");
```

[PHP Manual Link for Global variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

For a variable scope you can see this [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: `$GLOBALS['var']` is perfectly fine.

Comment: you are not declaring variable as global in the question so I gave reason for declaration. yes string format of variable works.